# Ошибка при установки пакета Python (pip) из tar.gz

Tags: python-3.x, linux, pip, зависимости

В условиях замкнутого пространства (нет доступа к интернету) пакеты в систему устанавливаются из "исходников" (`soupsieve-2.2.1.tar.gz`), которые скачаны с http://pypi.org и распакованы в директорию проекта.

Далее командой `pip install -e` устанавливаются в виртуальное окружение.

Но при установке пакета `soupsieve` возникает следующая ошибка:

```bash
 (venv) $> pip install -e soupsieve-2.2.1 
Obtaining file:///home/user/ProjectName/packages/soupsieve-2.2.1
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /home/user/ProjectName/venv/bin/python3.8 /tmp/pip-standalone-pip-onkde4g_/__env_pip__.zip/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-r5z6zk0v/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=42' wheel
       cwd: None
  Complete output (9 lines):
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f62f45b0430>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Неизвестное имя или служба')': /simple/setuptools/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f62f45b02b0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Неизвестное имя или служба')': /simple/setuptools/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f62f45b01f0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Неизвестное имя или служба')': /simple/setuptools/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f62f45b0d00>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Неизвестное имя или служба')': /simple/setuptools/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f62f45b0eb0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Неизвестное имя или служба')': /simple/setuptools/
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools>=42 (from versions: none)
  ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools>=42
  WARNING: You are using pip version 21.1.1; however, version 21.2.4 is available.
  You should consider upgrading via the '/home/user/ProjectName/venv/bin/python3.8 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding file:///home/user/ProjectName/packages/soupsieve-2.2.1. Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/user/ProjectName/venv/bin/python3.8 /tmp/pip-standalone-pip-onkde4g_/__env_pip__.zip/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-r5z6zk0v/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=42' wheel Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/user/ProjectName/venv/bin/python3.8 /tmp/pip-standalone-pip-onkde4g_/__env_pip__.zip/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-r5z6zk0v/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'setuptools>=42' wheel Check the logs for full command output.
```

Для полноты картины.

```
(venv) $> pip list
Package    Version Location
---------- ------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------
asgiref    3.4.1   /home/user/ProjectName/packages/asgiref-3.4.1
Django     3.2.7   /home/user/ProjectName/packages/Django-3.2.7
pip        21.1.1
pytz       2021.3  /home/user/ProjectName/packages/pytz-2021.3
setuptools 58.2.0
sqlparse   0.4.2   /home/user/ProjectName/packages/sqlparse-0.4.2
wheel      0.37.0
```

Тут можно видеть, что пакеты `asgiref`, `pytz` и `sqlparse` установлены (`Django` имеет в зависимостях перечисленные выше пакеты, которые ставятся ранее его самого).

### P.S.

Если пакет устанавливать обычным путём, то есть из интернета, всё устанавливается нормально.

Comment: в документации к пакету написано, что должен быть установлен beautifulsoup перед его установкой.

Comment: beautifulsoup4-4.10.0 - без этой утилиты не устанавливается

Comment: добавьте ` --no-deps` - тогда установится только целевой пакет, без проверки зависимостей. Проблема в том, что вызывается `pip` с опцией `--ignore-installed` -- установленные пакеты игнорируются и все зависимости загружаются заново.

Comment: Вам не нужно указывать `-e`, достаточно просто задать относительный путь к файлу пакета: `pip3 install ./soupsieve-2.2.1-py3-none-any.whl`